# Is there a way I can accurately calculate the CR of my homebrewed monster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, homebrew, cr-calculation

In my current 3.5 Epic level campaign, I am trying to make 11 monsters around the CR of a [hecatoncheire](http://dndsrd.net/epicMonsters.html#hecatoncheires), however, my googling skills have failed me and I can’t find any reliable way to calculate their CR.  Is there a guide or formula I can use?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I suck at spelling, the creatures I’m making are divine guardians, and the requisites to become one are to defeat a hecatoncheire alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There's no formula and there's nothing *reliable*, but there *is* a guide (although its suggestions aren't very helpful)

The *Monster Manual* on Creating the Monster on Challenge Rating, in part, says, "The two basic tools for determining [a new monster's] CR are comparing and playtesting" (302). Too long to reproduce here, the section then goes on to explain *how* to do those two things… in over 1,000 words.

To summarize, the *Monster Manual* largely agrees with [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/119442/8610) that there isn't anything that's absolutely carved in stone about putting a Challenge Rating to a new monster. The most accurate way to determine a custom monster's Challenge Rating is playtesting: have the monster engage the PCs in *your* campaign several times in mock encounters and assign the new monster a Challenge Rating based on its average performance.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

CR is wonkey even on lower levels, and CRs are accurate only in the sense that it’s exactly the CR that the author meant to give that creature.

And the situation gets even worse: As @KRyan commented, there's also the *'basic, impossible-to-balance instability of the epic rules themselves, on top of the general problem with CR'* to consider.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the basic, impossible-to-balance instability of the epic rules themselves, on top of the general problem with CR.